# Visualforce page rendered as PDF giving problem when called in page layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, renderas

I have created a visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract__c" extensions="ContractPDFControllerExtension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" renderAs="PDF" >
    <apex:form >
      <apex:outputtext value="{!htmlText}" escape="false" />
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class ContractPDFControllerExtension {

Public String htmlText{get;set;}
public contractPDFControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
     string recordId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('Id');
     List<Contract__c> contractList = [Select id, Temp_Contract__c from Contract__c where id=:recordId ];
     htmlText=EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(contractList[0].Temp_Contract__c ).toString();

}

}
```

I want to add this page in page layout. But getting encoded values
[image]

How to get this VF page displayed in page layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe and provide the visualforce page link.

```
 <apex:page STAndardController="Contract__c">
  <iframe src="https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/PDFPage"></iframe>
</apex:page>
```